# python code for optimizing the output by genetic algorithm and Xgboost

Tags: xgboost, genetic-algorithm

My data is  numerical data with 6 inputs and 1 output. I have developed a predictive XGboost regression model in python.

Now I want to use the genetic algorithm to optimize the output (minimization). So I need a different combination of inputs (ex: [50,25,2,0,23,0],[60,0,20,0,10,10], [83,10,2,5,0,0]....etc.) generated by a genetic algorithm (where x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 = 100) and the outputs for each set of these inputs should be predicted by the XGboost predictive model which represented by (y_pred).

I fix the desired output (y_des) to be 50.

objective_fun = (y_pred) - (y-des) ≤ 5

Otherwise program should go back to the genetic algorithm and ask to generate a new set of inputs and for this new set of inputs, the output will be predicted by XGboost. the loops should continue until get the desired.

For this I need coding in python. I request you to help me in this regard.

i am expecting the code for my problem in python